# How to transform a function from f[#1] to f[x]

Tags: functions, variable

So I have this function :

```
Sqrt[-1 + Tanh[#1 - #2]^2] &
```

How can I transform it into

```
f[x_,y_]=Sqrt[-1 + Tanh[x - y]^2]
```

I tried

```
Sqrt[-1 + Tanh[#1 - #2]^2] &/. #1 -> x /. #2 -> y /. & -> 1
```

But apparently  /. & -> 1 doesn't work

Comment: instead of using repeated `/.`s, use `expr /. {x -> a, y -> b, z -> c}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, the easy way is to evaluate it for `[x,y]`.

```
f[x_, y_] = Sqrt[-1 + Tanh[#1 - #2]^2] &[x, y];
```

If you'd rather do it with a replacement, you should understand the `FullForm` because that's what replacement works on.

```
Sqrt[-1 + Tanh[#1 - #2]^2] & // FullForm
(*
  Function[Sqrt[Plus[-1,Power[Tanh[Plus[Slot[1],Times[-1,Slot[2]]]],2]]]]
*)
```

So, you want to remove `Function`.

```
Sqrt[-1 + Tanh[#1 - #2]^2] & /. {Slot[1] -> x, Slot[2] -> y, Function -> Identity}
(*
  Sqrt[-1+Tanh[x-y]^2]
*)
```

Answer (score 13):

I think the easiest way would be to define(name) the pure function f

```
f = Sqrt[-1 + Tanh[#1 - #2]^2] &
```

and use it accordingly

```
f[x,y] 
(*Sqrt[-1 + Tanh[x - y]^2]*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general function, which I think protects the body of the `Function` from being evaluated:

```
def[Function[body_], f_] := 
 With[{nvar = Max@Cases[Hold[body], Slot[k_] :> k, Infinity]},
  With[{vars = Thread[
      ToExpression[
       Table["x" <> ToString@k, {k, nvar}],
       StandardForm, 
       Hold],
      Hold]},
   vars /. Hold[v_] :> Block[v,
      Hold[SetDelayed][
        Hold[f] @@ (Pattern[#, Blank[]] & /@ v),
        Hold[body] /. Slot[k_] :> RuleCondition[v[[k]]]
        ] // ReleaseHold
      ]
   ]]
```

Example:

```
ClearAll[fff];
xx = 2; x1 = 4;
def[xx + #2 - #1^2 &, fff]

DownValues@fff
(*  {HoldPattern[fff[x1_, x2_]] :> xx + x2 - x1^2}  *)
```

OP's:

```
def[Sqrt[-1 + Tanh[#1 - #2]^2] &, f]
DownValues@f
(*  {HoldPattern[f[x1_, x2_]] :> Sqrt[-1 + Tanh[x1 - x2]^2]}  *)
```